# UIPickerView selection row with click event, not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I created `UIPickerView` but I did not find a way to select row with click event.I can only select row with scrolling picker rows.

Is there any way to select a row with click event?

Comment: What do you mean by click event? Can you provide more detail about what you want to do?

Comment: For example, I have pickerview with 5 rows, I want to select third row with clicking third row, I do not want to slip pickerview to third row

Comment: That's not a good idea actually. If you want to click and select an option then you should use a tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Click event is not possible in `UIPickerView`.

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get `CGPoint` and then calculate index of row clicked. But I will highly recommend not to do such things (Apple may reject the App) as `PickerView` is all about scrolling the list.